# jquery datepicker getTime not UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, utc

I have the following code which works fine until the datepicker reaches BST.

```
var i;
function showEventDates(date) {
  for (i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
    if (date.getTime() == startDates[i]) {
      return [true, 'eventDay'];
    }
  }    
  return [false, ''];
}
var startDates = new Array();

$("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
  startDates.push(Date.UTC.apply(Date, this.value.split(",").map(Number)));
});

$('#mydate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: showEventDates
});
```

During BST the line `if (date.getTime() == startDates[i]) {` returns false because there's an hour difference.

Any ideas how I can get these to match? I think it's the datepicker time that's not UTC.

EDIT:

An example of an option from select.startdates is

```
<option value="2013, 2, 1">01/03/2013</option>
```

Comment: The time might be localized, I'll go look at the doc

Comment: @HugoDozois - Yeah... any idea how I can "unlocalize" it??

Comment: @Tom: the `getTimezoneOffset` method of the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object returns the offset in minutes. You can use that to convert a local date to UTC.

Comment: @Martijn: that sounds good. I've fried my brain looking at this now. Can you give a hint as to how I'd use that?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the datepicker doesn’t return UTC dates, but local ones (which is actually the default in Javascript).

To convert your constructed dates to local time:

```
$("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
  var d = Date.UTC.apply(Date, this.value.split(",").map(Number));
  d = d + new Date(d).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // convert UTC to local
  startDates.push(d);
});
```

Normally, I’d use the `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor instead of the `Date.UTC` function, but you can’t use `apply` with the `Date` constructor.

If you’d rather leave your startDates array in UTC, then you need to convert the datepicker’s dates to UTC:

```
function showEventDates(date) {
  date = date - new Date(date).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // convert local to UTC
  // for ...
}
```

NB: choose one *or* the other of these methods, not both, or you’ll end up with the same problem... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hear there are some timezone updates to the jQuery datetimepicker so you may want to check the site first, however here is what I did to get the selected date & time in UTC format.

First create the datetimepicker and use cities instead of +0500 GMT because if you use GMT offsets you have to take into account daylight savings - and that is a nightmare.

```
 // create ye datetimepicker with timezone options 
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    showTimezone: true,
    onSelect: onSelect,
    timezoneList: [
      { value: 'America/New_York', label: 'New York'},
      { value: 'America/Chicago', label: 'Chicago' } ,
      { value: 'America/Denver', label: 'Denver' },
      { value: 'America/Los_Angeles', label: 'Los Angeles' }
    ]);
```

Next, grab the timezoneJS.Date library from [mde on Github](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) (NOTE: you will also need to download the appropriate timezone files for your region, just follow the README instructions)

Now when the user selects a date the onSelect method gets called.

```
function onSelect(dateText, dateInst) {
  // get the date without the timezone data
  var d = $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('getDate');

  // init timezoneJS
  timezoneJs.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/tz';
  timezoneJs.timezone.init();

  // get the selected timezone
  var tz = $('#datetimepicker').data('datepicker').settings.timepicker.timezone

  // construct the utcDate with the help of the timezoneJS.Date lib
  var utcDate = new timezoneJS.Date(
    d.getFullYear(),
    d.getMonth(),
    d.getDate(),
    d.getHours(),
    d.getMinutes(),
    tz)
  var utcLinuxTimestamp = utcDate.getTime() / 1000    
}
```

Not exactly painless, but it takes care of the daylight savings stuff for you.

The reverse of this to populate a datetimepicker with a date and a timezone from a UTC timestamp looks like this:

```
// init timezone JS
timezoneJs.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/tz';
timezoneJs.timezone.init();

// get timezone date JS object
var tz = 'America/New York';
var d = new timezoneJS.Date( timestamp * 1000, tz);

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  showTimezone: true,
  timezoneList: [ 
      { value: 'America/New_York', label: 'New York'},
      { value: 'America/Chicago', label: 'Chicago' } ,
      { value: 'America/Denver', label: 'Denver' },
      { value: 'America/Los_Angeles', label: 'Los Angeles' }
    ],
  timezone: tz,
  defaultDate: d._dateProxy,
  onSelect: onSelect
}).datepicker('setDate',d._dateProxy);
```

I'm not certain if you need the setDate part on the last line, but couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Martijn comment:

```
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

if (date.getTime() - offset == startDates[i]) 
{
      return [true, 'eventDay'];
}
```